# Ubuntu How to delete files older than certain file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

There are several files, How to delete files older than certain file X (order by last modified date)?

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type f ! -newer someFileX -exec rm "{}" \;
```

"Not newer than" not very exactly however